# Repository for free icons

Tags: android, icons, repository

Is there any repository with free icons for using in Android? I'd like to use icons defined with three states: regular, selected and pressed. I know that for Desktop applications there are many repositories, but for Android I only find PSD files.

Thanks ^_^

Comment: try this http://www.icon-king.com/projects/nuvola/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at following link, it contains a lot of free Icon Sets and links to various other sites -

http://androgeek.com/android-icon-packs-basics-and-a-list-of-free-icon-sets/

Answer (score 0):

Check Font Awesome. Over 300 icons. New icons added regularly. There are two ways to include it in your project.

- Generate custom pngs here: http://fa2png.io

  OR
- Include as font [How to use icons and symbols from "Font Awesome" on Native Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210548/how-to-use-a-icons-and-symbols-from-font-awesome-on-native-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

The best I found with over 22,000 free SVG Icons: [Free Icons](https://free-icons.github.io/free-icons)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34617387)