# android chrome browser is geting defferent font-size in portrait and landscape mode

Tags: jquery, css, html

i have upload screen short here,
i have no idea, why android browser geting different font size
portrait and landscape mode[image: portrait mode]

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var x=$(".main").css("font-size");
 alert(x)
});
```

```css
.main{
 font-size:18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>


<body>


<div class="main">
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: landscape mode]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting

[Android, how to display font awesome icons in layout edit mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150677/android-how-to-display-font-awesome-icons-in-layout-edit-mode)

check this two link ,its help you to find your answer