# How to use font-awesome in edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-drawable, font-awesome

So far I've used the following code to add the icon

```
EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf" );
email.setTypeface(font);
```

But the icon gets added as a value of the edittext field. Whereas I want the icon to appear at the left. I also know about the android:drawableLeft attribute but it requires I drawable resource i.e a jpeg and not a ttf. How can I solve this problem. Thanks
[image]

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210548/how-to-use-a-icons-and-symbols-from-font-awesome-on-native-android-application

Comment: That's what I did. But the icon gets added as a value in the edittext field

Comment: because it's a font, not an Image. You can use two textviews in a linearlayout to get the desired result, but you can't use an Icon as a font and simultaenously using it as a textfield

Comment: I want the icon to be placed in the textfield like shown here http://reachout.herokuapp.com/users/sign_in . Any idea how do I do that?

Comment: sorry, i'm not able to open this link from my workplace. Can you upload the Image to your post so I can have a look?

Comment: @Frame91 Added the screenshot. Please have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55501/discussion-between-akshay-takkar-and-frame91).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for font awesome in android apps i suggest https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify

but that would not fix your issue as the icon still would be a part of the value.
to avoid this you might want to use https://github.com/DayS/EnhancedEditText which uses the android-iconify library to achieve what you want :)

good luck

Comment: The library is too old. The solution of @christopher-smit is better.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the following Stack Overflow post.

[How to use icon from font file as a drawable in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367883/how-to-use-icon-from-font-file-as-a-drawable-in-android)

Then use it:

```
mEmailView = findViewById(R.id.login_email);

FontDrawable user = new FontDrawable(this, getString(R.string.fa_fa_user_circle_o), iconFont);
user.sizePx((int)mEmailView.getTextSize());
user.colorRes(R.color.white);
mEmailView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(user, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I solve this problem.

Use a PNG or JPEG.

Or, create (or find) a `Drawable` that renders text in a font, and use `setCompoundDrawables()` to associate such a drawable with your `EditText` at runtime.