# Dynamically Set Font Icon from Code using FontAwesome without String.xml

Tags: android, font-awesome, custom-font

I am trying to load font icon using fontawesome.ttf in a textView. 
If i set the string value like `&#xf007;` through string.xml then it works file and Icon is shown. But if the same text `"&#xf007;"` is set programatically as
 `textView.setText("&#xf007;")` 
then it doesn't show the icon , rather the same text is shown on textview.

Any alternative approach to show icons programatically without referring string.xml file ?

Comment: Ok, I'll set it as an answer, so you can accept it and remove it from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried converting the string with base 16 integer and it worked fine.

```
new String(Character.toChars(Integer.parseInt(
                        str, 16)))
```

str has the unicode value like f007.

Comment: Works like charm.!

Comment: Thanks alot, simplest fix.

Answer (score 12):

Try using the Unicode code... `\uf007`.
This should work just fine:

```
textView.setText("\uf007");
```

Comment: HI @DerGolem , if i hardcode the string to the textview  like textView.setText("\uf007"); then it works fine but the same string if i get it from server and set it to textview then it just shows "\uf007". Any idea if i have to convert / encode the string to set in textview ?

Comment: `if i get it from server` ptobably, the server uses a different encoding from **Unicode UTF-8**... Try passing (from server) something like `[user-icon]`, then client-side, replace it with `uf007`

Comment: @FrankN.Stein i am not able to set icon in textview, try both string from server like &#xf0e0; and [&#xf0e0;] and set to text but it set only &#xf0e0; not icon. can you please elaborate?

Comment: Simply replace " &#xf0e0;" with "\uf007".

Answer (score 2):

This is the good example I found so far.

**[ORIGINAL ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210548/how-to-use-a-icons-and-symbols-from-font-awesome-on-native-android-application#15762875)**

copy & paste from the answer:

1. Copied `fontawesome-webfont.ttf` into your assests folder
2. Found the character entities for icons I wanted, using this page: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/
3. Created an entry in strings.xml for each icon. Eg for a heart:

   `<string name="icon_heart">&#xf004;</string>`
4. Referenced said entry in the view of your xml layout:

> `<Button
>            android:id="@+id/like"
>            ...
>            android:text="@string/icon_heart" />`

5. Loaded the font in my onCreate method and set it for the appropriate Views:

> `Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf" );
>       Button button = (Button)findViewById( R.id.like );
>       button.setTypeface(font);`

Don't forgot to use `setTypeface()`

Comment: So far, the best answer. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in xml and then use

```
getString(R.string.fa_star_o);
```

Work fine