# android studio and material design icons

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

Does android studio come with material design icons and if so, where are there? There seem to a few plugins around. But I think I came across a library of icons in android studio but can't remember where!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import material design icons into an android project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684759/import-material-design-icons-into-an-android-project)

Answer (score 9):

In Android Studio

File > New > Vector Asset
Here you can choose an existing icon or import a local SVG file

Answer (score 2):

In my experience Android Studio doesn't provide an own material design icons pack.

There is a plugin that can help you to generate a set of icons from an image:

- [Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7647?pr=)
- [Source](https://github.com/konifar/android-material-design-icon-generator-plugin)

Also you can use the official icon pack provided by Google:

- [Google Material Guide line](http://www.google.com/design/spec/resources/sticker-sheets-icons.html#sticker-sheets-icons-components)
- [Material pack from Google on Github](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons)

Of course you can import the icons that you need in your projects, but not inside the Android Studio resources in general.

Comment: Good plugin! You can also install it directly in Android Studio via Preferences/Plugins. Click Browse repositorys, type Material in the search box and you will see the plugin.