# How to get minus and plus image buttons in android

Tags: material-design, android-resources, android-imagebutton

```java
ImageButton plusButton = new ImageButton(context);
plusButton.setImageResource(x);
```

I need some resource to put in place of `x` in the above code line, such as, to achieve something like the minus and plus button shown near the phone number field in the image below:

[image]

But I don't know where the resource of these images lie. So please help me out with that. Thank you.

Comment: Use the answer from this post:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684759/import-material-design-icons-into-an-android-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684759/import-material-design-icons-into-an-android-project)

Answer (score 8):

The icon for the minus sign is called "remove" in the Material Design Icon set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Menu](http://androiddrawables.com/Menu.html) or if you want id:

```
getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.*);
```

and search under data/res/drawable.

Comment: I meant, do you know the exact resource 'android.R.drawable.*' to get the minus symbol shown in the image. I'm not finding the resource for that.          P.S I have found the resource for plus button which is 'android.R.drawable.ic_input_add'

Comment: did you search data folder?

Comment: I've typed android.R.drawable and then searched in the auto-complete suggestions by android studio. Nothing fits in, exactly for the minus sign shown in the image. I've found big red cross buttons, but I feel it would make the layout clumsy, so I've decided to just go with the plus buttons leaving out the minus buttons. Maybe, the minus button was was custom made, who knows?