# android: show font icon as a sequence of number string

Tags: android, font-awesome

I want to put a [`Font-Awesome`](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/) icon inside `textview` text. After I set the text, android shows me a string sequence instead of font-icon.

My code is:

```
String formatedSection = formatedSection + sections.get(i).getContent() +getResources().getString(R.string.icon_ref);
```

I define icon_ref in string.xml as below:

```
 <string name="icon_ref">&#xf075;</string>
```

I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210548/how-to-use-a-icons-and-symbols-from-font-awesome-on-native-android-application) to add font-icon. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you copy the font file into your asset folder

Comment: @ Ahmad Alsanie  yes i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did step 5 in that short guid your problem seem to forget that there is a diff between java and XML.

> In XML you use XML escape (&...;), in Java you'll probably have to use Java escape (\u...). –  Biffen May 20 at 10:10

Try to hard code the string into "\uf075" and it would work like a charm.