# fontawesome fa-hourglass [&#xf254;] not supported

Tags: android, font-awesome

I use a fontawesome-webfont.ttf font file in my assets folder.

my layout file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/shop_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/fa_search"
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
```

My string file:

```
 <string name="fa_hourglass">&#xf252;</string>
```

My java file:

```
itemView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
itemView .setTypeface(font);
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959751/how-to-use-font-awesome-icon-in-android-application

Answer (score 0):

Because in the string.xml file you have defined the string

```
<string name="fa_hourglass">&#xf252;</string>
```

But in your `TextView` you used the wrong string

```
  android:text="@string/fa_search"
```

so change the text to this

```
  android:text="@string/fa_hourglass"
```

Comment: sir this is exp i use   android:text="@string/fa_hourglass" but is not work

Comment: some font file is support but some not i.e fa_hourglass"