# Add fontawesome icons in my toolbar items menu

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to add `Font Awesome` library to my android project but i just can't. I was reading each google result about this topic.

My `menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/buzon"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_buzon"
        android:title="@string/buzon" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/objetivos"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_objetivos"
        android:title="@string/objetivos" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/home_action"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_go_home"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/encuesta"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_encuesta"
        android:title="@string/encuesta" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/cursos"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_cursos"
        android:title="@string/cursos" />

</menu>
```

I'm want to use `Font Awesome` icons in my items menu instead default android icons.

For references, i was trying to follow this guide without success.

> [How to use Font Awesome icon in android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959751/how-to-use-font-awesome-icon-in-android-application)

Comment: try this library : https://www.androidhive.info/2019/06/use-font-awesome-icons-android/

Comment: I'll read it @yathavan thank you