# why is getting a string from xml resource and getting it programmatrically different?

Tags: java, android

I have a string resource in xml

```
<string name="contoh">&#xf080;</string>
```

and then I call from java

```
String res = getString(R.string.contoh);
String langsung = "&#xf080;";
```

after I display the output is different, like this image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXuwk.png)

please help, how to convert that string from java to become like string from xml, because I want to display icon from API using that code
Thank you

SOLVED in this, in accepted answer,

[Unicode characters not displayed in TextView.setText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522337/unicode-characters-not-displayed-in-textview-settext)

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#xf080;"));
```

Comment: please don't post links to images, post your information in the question itself

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959751/how-to-use-font-awesome-icon-in-android-application

Comment: Okay, sorry for my mistake, solved in my edited post

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse color with:

```
String langsung = "&#xf080;";
Color myColor = Color.parseColor(langsung)
```

Comment: Hi Jose, this is not color, this is a word or text usual, i need to display icon from this library https://github.com/ravi8x/Android-Font-Awesome, but in the example it display icon from string xml resource, i need to display from string java

Comment: Oh, now I understand you. It is such a weird thing what you want to do, and I think it is impossible.
Strings in XML are added to the project at compile time, not runtime.