# How to change the colour of icon in android.

Tags: android, material-design

I have downloaded a check icon(24 dp) from android material design library from the link https://design.google.com/icons/. There are only two colours available black and white, but I need the colour of tick icon to be a shade of green(I have the colour hex code). How do I change the colour of icon in android and how do I change the shape as well. The shape that we get are square or circular. I need elliptical at one end and square at the other. Do I need to use some design tools for that. Thank you.

Comment: GO to http://www.flaticon.com/ and download icon with your color

Comment: search for background tint.. supports api API 21+

Answer (score 1):

try with this excellent service

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Answer (score 1):

make a selector for checked and unchecked icon like this

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

         <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
         <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" />

    </selector>
```

and apply it on checkbox using button attribute like this

```
 android:button="@drawable/<your selector>"
```

You can use **flaticon.com** for checked and unchecked button

Answer (score 0):

Download icon from https://icons8.com/. In this you can change color of icon as you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TintImageView` within the appcompat support library and then tinting/coloring the imageview is by simply calling the `android:backgroundTint` to tint the imageview into one color.
add this line to your dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v24:+'
```

and then

```
<TintImageView
android:layout_width=""
android:layout_height="" 
android:src=""
android:backgroundTint="@color/green"/>
```

so the above xml will tint the imageView to color green.

Answer (score 0):

1- Download font file from [this page](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/iconfont) 
2- Found the character entities for icons, using this page. For example [alarm_on](https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_alarm_on) 
3- Use like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15762875/1107607) example
4- Change android:textColor property from xml file

Answer (score 0):

```
android:tint="#ffffff"
```

Add this attribute to the image view element.