# how to use Font awesome icons in dynamically on android application?

Tags: android

this is my code,

```
String str = "&#xe013;"; // this my dynamic font code
```

ref url is
[How to use icons and symbols from "Font Awesome" on Native Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210548/how-to-use-a-icons-and-symbols-from-font-awesome-on-native-android-application)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this library on [GitHub](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics) that allows you to easily create a drawable from the FontAwesome icons.

Answer (score 0):

> I know its very late, use unicode like

```
textawesome.setText(new String(Character.toChars(Integer.parseInt(
            "e013".getIcon_unicode(), 16))));
```