# (Android) font-awesome icons not showing

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to use font-awesome icons and having some problem. It worked from MainActivity but when I use from Fragment its not showing up the icons.

This is my HomeFragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  View home = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
  View feed_row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_row, container, false);

  like_button = (Button) feed_row.findViewById(R.id.like_button);
  Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
  like_button.setTypeface(tf);

  mHomeFeed = (RecyclerView) home.findViewById(R.id.home_feed);
  mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
  mHomeFeed.setHasFixedSize(true);
  mHomeFeed.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

This is feed_row.xml:

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/like_button"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/icon_heart"
   android:background="@color/noBackground"/>
```

Strings.xml

```
<string name="icon_heart">&#xf004;</string>
<string name="icon_comment">&#xf0e5;</string>
```

What should I do now? It had no error but icons looked like below:

[image: this]

Answer (score 0):

Instead using:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), 
                                       "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
```

which has memory issues because constantly creating a new typeface for each icon (as in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15762875/4758255) comment), you can use [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy). Where after you have configured your app with the library, you only need to add `fontPath` attribute:

So you have a more and flexible code, where the font is only in the XML:

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/like_button"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/icon_heart"
   android:background="@color/noBackground"
   fontPath="fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making a class and extends it from `Button` class like this

```
public class AwesomeFontButton extends Button {

    public AvenirBookEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public AvenirBookEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public AvenirBookEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                    "fontawesome-webfont.ttf"); //add your font path here
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }

}
```

and use it in xml like this:

```
<YourFilePath.AwesomeFontButton 
   android:id="@+id/like_button"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/icon_heart"
   android:background="@color/noBackground"/>
```

use it in xml wherever you need