# Android special Unicode characters

Tags: android, fonts

I am currently developing an app which displays special unicode characters (e.g. `ꁴ`)

Now I encountered that on older devices those symbols can not be displayed.
How can I know if it works on the current device or not?

1. Do I have to create an Virtual Android Device for each SDK-Version and test?
2. Would it be possible to bundle the current Roboto Font into my apk and deliver it to older devices so that the characters will be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

if place your custom font in assets folder and address when used you will not have an issue

1. place your Roboto.ttf in assests folder
2. Created an entry in strings.xml for each icon.  Eg for a "Yi Syllable Bby":

   ```
   <string name="icon_note">&#41076;</string>
   ```
3. Referenced said entry in the view of my xml layout:

   ```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/like"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        ...
        android:text="@string/icon_note" />
   ```

Loaded the font in my onCreate method and set it for the appropriate Views:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "Roboto.ttf" );
...
Button button = (Button)findViewById( R.id.like );
button.setTypeface(font);
```

it can be used to use icon lib as font check here [How to use icons and symbols from "Font Awesome" on Native Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210548/how-to-use-icons-and-symbols-from-font-awesome-on-native-android-application)