# Passing Flutter icons to android java

Tags: java, android, flutter, icons

I am trying to find a way to pass parameters from my flutter/dart app to a plugin I am writing in java. 
My goal is to let the dart code pass a standard `Icon` as parameters to the plugin and the latter showing it in an `ImageView`. My attempts are to pass the `IconData` containing the font and the unicode for the icon as well as the hex color of that icon. On the the plugin side, there will be a retrieval of that icon using the `IconData` and applying the color via from the hex color.

I can pass the arguments to the plugin like any other `String` argument but I didn't find a way to do the java part. I have tried creating `Bitmaps` and then changing their colors but that didn't work at all.

I am asking if there is a known way to passing icons from dart to flutter especially when they are based on external fonts?

Comment: Something similar has been already asked eg. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210548/how-to-use-icons-and-symbols-from-font-awesome-on-native-android-application

Comment: @nvi9 yeah I saw those answers, it I still not the one I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the image name as a string to your android plugin and use AssetManager to get the path to as described in [flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#loading-flutter-assets-in-android).

for example:

```
    val assetManager: AssetManager = registrar.context().assets
    val key: String = registrar.lookupKeyForAsset("image")
    val fd = assetManager.openFd(key)
    val image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fd.createInputStream())
```