# How to use FontAwsome icon as the body of notification in react-native that uses Notifee library

Tags: html, react-native, notifications, font-awesome

I'm using [Notifee](https://notifee.app) library for showing notification in my react-native application. based on this [documentation](https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/android/appearance) it seems I should use html tags for styling the title and body of notification.

In my case, I want to add a fontAwsome icon inside of notification body.

Now the following html tags work in the html file but don't work on notification

```
<i class="far fa-clock"></i>
```

**This is the result in web page:**

[image]

**Bu the result of notification body is empty:**

[image]

**Also you can see my code;**

```
const customBody =
      '<html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><!--Get your own code at fontawesome.com--></head><body><i class="far fa-clock"></i></body></html>';

    await notifee.displayNotification({
      id: notification.id,
      title: 'This is title',
      body: customBody,
      data: {
        [notification.key]: notification.data,
      },
      android: androidConfig,
      ios: iOSConfig,
    });
```

And also any alternative solution is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

interesting scenario! I think this can be possible but not by embedding any scripts. There are only a handful of HTML tags that are supported ([see string-resource#StylingWithHTM](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML)L).

I'm wondering if you could do something like adding a [custom typeface](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#example---adding-a-custom-typeface)
or exploring using FontAwesome as a font family.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210548/how-to-use-icons-and-symbols-from-font-awesome-on-native-android-application) is an interesting thread on how to use FontAwesome as a typeface.

An alternative solution would be to use [emojis](https://gist.github.com/oliveratgithub/0bf11a9aff0d6da7b46f1490f86a71eb/)